# Can I get the Name of a list item as well as its Title using REST?

Tags: 2013, rest

I am currently using the REST interface to retrieve information about Items in a SharePoint List:

```
https://myserver/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<guid>')/Items(<id>)
```

The data returned includes the `Title` of each List Item, but not the `Name`. Since `Title` is not mandatory, this makes it difficult for me to use the data as is.

I can make another call to the REST interface to get the details of the File:

```
https://myserver/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<guid>')/Items(<id>)/File
```

and use the details there, but I was hoping to avoid two REST calls to do this. Is there another way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand properties of `File` object as below

```
https://siteurl/_api/lists/getbytitle('documents')/items?$expand=file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could consider the following options to retrieve `ListItem.Title` &  `File.Name` using a single request:

**Option 1: Using `FileLeafRef` property**

```
https://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listtitle>')/items(<itemid>)?$select=Title,FileLeafRef
```

**Option 2: Using `File.Name` property**

```
https://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listtitle>')/items(<itemid>)?$select=Title,File/Name&$expand=File
```